# How to setup Indian rupee format in Numbers?

Tags: text, numbers, internationalization, formatting

Indian rupee number format is different from US number format. 
e.g. 1,00,00,00,000
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee

How do I setup a custom number format in Numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention which version of Numbers you were using.  Here are general directions to create a custom cell format in both [Numbers '08 (1.0)](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Numbers/1.0/en/c3la22.html) and [Numbers '09 (2.0)](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Numbers/2.0/en/lsoe6f9fd59.html).

In Numbers '09, once in the *Custom Number Format* dialog, drag a few integer elements into the format box.  Pull the menu down for each, and choose *Hide separator*.  On the appropriate groups, change the number of digits to two.

[image: Screenshot of Custom Number Format dialog]

If you're not mixing with USD and prefer India's conventions, a much simpler approach is in the [*Language & Text* panel of *System Preferences*](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-set-snow-leopards-language-text-preferences.html).  Choose *India* from the *Region* menu, and any cells set to *Currency* format will not only have the correct symbol, but the correct groupings.  Of course, then if you want USD formatted correctly, you'd need a custom format for that - so use whichever region is most appropriate to the bulk of your content.

Comment: Great, is there a way to not suppress unwanted commas for smaller number. e.g. I am seeing ,,,15,000 for 15,000